# Bone roll not mirroring correctly

Tags: rigging

I'm am having a really bad time with Blender lately and im hoping i can have some answers to a specific problem. After using Symmetrize on the left side of my rig, the position of the bones are correct but if turn my orientation on in the armature tab, i notice that the roll of the bones has been inverted along the x axis and i cant seem to get it fixed. 
I have tried applying all the transformations to the armature, rigify armatures are also inverted. Recalculating the roll along every axis doesnt seem to work either[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL7mn.png)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmesY.png)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ALR.png)
[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUSf.png)

I have tried pretty much everything i could find on the internet and im quite stumped since i cant move on to animation.
If anybody could help me i would really appreciate it! thanks! 
[Here is the link to my .blend file](https://mega.nz/#!Vko0hQxL!Vj_T1hL18F1MP4DEVL3LwAhLC_VitPutRMoIZJgGRXI)

Bones pointing along the world y axis have their roll correctly mirrored.
I am expecting most of my rig to look like the bones in the third picture. 4th picture is a simplified version of my problem.

Comment: If all bones share the same axis setup (in Blender they do), mirrored bones will not be able to completely represent mirrored behaviour. If you  are looking for an easy fix to transfer the current roll from one side to another, try the following: [1] In Bone Edit Mode check *X-Mirror* [2] Select the bones on one side, press Ctrl+R, type 0, then hit Enter.

Comment: I have already tried that before with no luck. Another detail is that all bones facing forward along the world y axis are correctly mirrored. Also every other model i download with a rig setup has the same issue

Comment: Could you supply a simplified example (just one original and one mirrored joint), with the current problem and illustrate how you wish the axes to be?

Comment: I have added a few more pictures to describe my issue, the ankles and feet of my rig are mirrored exactly but everything else has its z or x axis pointing in the opposite direction. I also added a simplified version of the issue as you asked. Thanks for helping btw!

Comment: Slightly tricky to explain, youre welcome to join me during the next 2h. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75066/riggingquestion

Comment: You should write an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to post my answer oops, but Leander has cleared things up for me. Basically i cant mirror a bone axis exactly and this bone roll behavior is normal
and during animation i have to set certain roll modes depending on what the bone is actually suppose to accomplish. Quaternion is better along bones with a vertical axis while horizontal seems to prefer regular xyz Euler coordinates. This allows me to mirror my pose correctly.