# Mirrored bones have flipped rotations

Tags: rigging, workflow

*This seems to be a fairly well known issue however I still cannot understand if there is a real solution or a workaround from what I've seen in my hunt for answers.*

I've made half a rig, mirrored it to the other side, zeroed out the bone rolls, all looks well except for the fact that the bone rotations are not how it should be. I want the bones to actually be truly mirrored in across the X-axis.

[image: top down view]

I have rigged in 3ds max and the same issue can be quite easily fixed with a few button toggles or you can resort to manually fixing the rotation on each bone yourself.

Here's how it looks **as of now:**

[image: local X bad]
[image: local y bad]
[image: local z bad]

*No good. Only the local X rotation (first pic) is working as I want it to. The other two axis are flipped and is the main issue I want to fix.*

---

Here's how i **want it** to look:

[image: local Y good]
[image: local Z good]

From what I've gathered, apparently it's technically working as intended. okay cool, so how do I make it so that its the way I want it?

---

[This post has the same problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104947/bone-roll-not-mirroring-correctly) I am experiencing but there was no clear answer as OP was helped through private messages rather than the discussion being visible to public. The summary OP gave at the end is not very helpful in understanding the issue.

**-Heres the blend file-**

[image]

Comment: 1) Make sure your armature is "facing" world -Y, and that rotation is applied. Make sure that your arm bones have the same name, which differs only by .r and .l suffixes.  2) Select your left arm bones in edit mode.  Use the "symmetrize" operation.  3) Enter pose and pose the bones of your left arm.  Select both bones, ctrl c, ctrl shift v.

Comment: If Nathan's answer doesn't fix your problem please share your file

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand your instructions all that clearly. at step 3 what do you mean by pose the bones? why would i be posing anything? once the arm bones have been symmetrised, everything is already in the correct position. And im also left a bit confused by what you mean by 'select both bones', you mean both arms/ every bone, as i have the hands rigged aswell.